# Visual elements in Livecharts?

Tags: c#, livecharts

I want to move a vertical line from the beginning of a Cartesian Chart to the end in a timespan of 5 seconds. I tried looking at the example provided in the website https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Visual%20Elements, but the UI Elements in the graph do not match with the code.

When I tried adding the line directly to the chart, the line works fine, but the chart is not showing up.

```
<lvc:CartesianChart Name="CartChart" Height="150" Zoom="Xy" Pan="Xy">

    <lvc:CartesianChart.Series>
        <lvc:LineSeries Values="{Binding audioPoints}" StrokeThickness="1" PointGeometry="{x:Null}" Visibility="Visible" />
    </lvc:CartesianChart.Series>

    <Line x:Name="anotherLine" Stroke="Black" Height="160" X1="0"X2="0" Y1="0" Y2="160"/>

</lvc:CartesianChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code example that I think will demonstrate what you need to do.  You should be able to translate most of it into databindings and xaml.

What's important to notice is that you add a VisualElement to the VisualElements collection on the CartesianChart.  You set the UIElement property on the VisualElement object to be the WPF control you want added to your chart.

https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wf/Visual%20Elements

```
    cartesianChart1.VisualElements.Add(new VisualElement
    {
        X = 0.5,
        Y = 7,
        HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
        UIElement = new TextBlock //notice this property must be a wpf control
        {
            Text = "Warning!",
            FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold,
            FontSize = 16,
            Opacity = 0.6
        }
    });

    cartesianChart1.VisualElements.Add(new VisualElement()
    {
            X=0,
            Y=myCalculatedValue,
            UIElement = new Rectangle()
            {
                Width= width,
                Margin= new Thickness(-seriesWidth/2, 0, 0, 0),
                Height=6,
                Fill=Brushes.Black,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top
            }
    });
```

Comment: I want to add a line, and line is not a wpf control.

Comment: You have to use a WPF UIElement.  I used a Rectangle with a small height in my code or you could use a WPF Polyline.  I updated my example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shapes.polyline?view=netframework-4.8